# A better way to check for Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a WEB APIcontroller which has some dependencies injected via Dependency injection. Now my question is do I have to check for null for these dependencies. If there is no check done then static code analysis tools flag it as an issue. 
I would like to know what is the general best practice to handle these scenarios. Would null object pattern be useful in this case
Below is the sample code.

```
public ExGatewayController(ILogger logger, IUtilityHelper utilityHelper)
{

    if (logger == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }
    if (utilityHelper == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(utilityHelper));
    }
    _utilityHelper = utilityHelper;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it as you have it.

Analysis tools can be configured and will pickup on certain things or not depending on what's important for the team you are part of and the rules already set.

Checking for nulls will make sure that no code will run unless you pass through something.

This is something I've seen a lot. Accept whatever, even nulls and then go through many layers and eventually something tries to use the thing and fails with an exception that is really difficult to track while debugging. Might as well stop things at the earliest chance, this will improve your application and reduce issues later on.

Yes, you can syntactic sugar like one of the previous answers suggests, but that is doing the same thing so it's not really changing anything other than fewer lines of code.

Bottom line, what you have is fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think in C#8 you can use  non-nullable reference types, something like this (Not sure if it works, I hope it has been released):

```
public ExGatewayController(ILogger! logger, IUtilityHelper! utilityHelper)
{
    _utilityHelper = utilityHelper;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/227

Comment: The syntax is reverse in C# 8. This means that, if you enable compiler checking, everything is non-null by default, and becomes nullable when you mark the type with a `?`, as in `ILogger?`. Do note that this is only a design-time check. No exception is thrown at runtime in case you do pass in `null`. C# 9 will (likely) get great syntax for this using the `!`, but in that case the `!` should be placed on the variable name, as in: `ILogger logger!, IUtilityHelper utilityHelper!`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Guards](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Guards/) library and write line

```
Guard.IsNotNull(logger, nameof(logger))
```

There is support for expression also like

```
Guard.IsNotNull(() => logger)
```

but I suppose it is more slow (comparing to first sample)

Answer (score 0):

Im using next variant:

```
public ExGatewayController(ILogger logger, IUtilityHelper utilityHelper)
{
    _utilityHelper = utilityHelper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(utilityHelper));;
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
}
```